# Detect collision between particles and nodes in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, collision, detection, scenekit

I have few nodes with a Kinematic phyisicsBodyType and I want it to interact with some particles System, and by that I mean that I want to detect collision and execute some code at the moment when node collide with nay particle from an particle system. I've found a way by adding an event handler, but I'm not quite sure how can I use it([link to method here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticleSystem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNParticleSystem/handleEvent:forProperties:withBlock:)).

Can someone explain me how can I use that event handler(preferred would be to explain me in Swift), or otherwise can you give me another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end was very simple. First, you have to assign an array of nodes to the `colliderNodes` property of particle system. After that, code in swift looks something like that:

```
    particleSystem.handleEvent(SCNParticleEvent.Collision, forPropierties:[SCNParticlePropertyContactPoint], withBlock: {
        (data: UnsabeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>>, dataStride: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, indicies: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>, count:Int) in 
        //code on detection collision goes here
})
```

Every parameter is briefly explained right in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticleSystem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNParticleSystem/handleEvent:forProperties:withBlock:).

Comment: If I want the particle to bounce when hitting an object, does this work as well?